# How to get `File` reference to external disk?

Tags: android

I would like to get in my file browser `File` reference to external disk not SD Card. I mean I know that there is method

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

But to my knowledge this will get reference to SD Card. But how to get external disk (say kind of USB storage attached to Android device)? You know that device can have both SD card and external USB stick attached to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have selected following solution:
1) Enlisting all existing roots using:

```
File[] roots=File.listRoots();
```

2) check presense among those roots standard ones, i.e.

```
File phoneRoot=new File("//");
File sdRoot=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

3) If there are some extra ones - treat them as those additional external disks/sticks

I think it's best solution, since no hacks, everything is standard and this covers possible future extensions.

Answer (score 1):

> But how to get external disk (say kind of USB storage attached to Android device)?

Android does not support this. If particular devices do, you would have to ask their manufacturers what they recommend.

Comment: I just saw several articles about using Android device as USB host. I have checked them again and found that in fact half of them hacks another half just false ones. Anyway I can't say that in the future Android device can't be used as USB hosts. Anyway thanx for response